# Kubeadm join: Fails while creating HA cluster with multiple master nodes

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, high-availability, kubeadm, flannel

I have `5 Vm in my GCP`, out of which three are supposed to be `master1, master2, master3` and other two are worker nodes `(worker1 & worker 2)`. I have created a `TCP Loadbalancer(LB)` to enable load balancing for the master nodes. I have two sections in the LB:

```
i)frontend ii)backend
```

In the backend, i have defined all master ips there. And the frontend, i generated a static public ip and given port `6443 as LB port`.

In master1, i sucessfully ran the `kubeadm init` command as follows:

```
kubeadm init --control-plane-endpoint="<LB_IP>:6443" --apiserver-advertise-address=10.128.0.2 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

where 10.128.0.2 is the master1 internal ip & 10.244.0.0/16 is the network cidr for the kube-flannel.

The kubeadm init runs sucessfully and gives two kubeadm join commands, one to join a new control plane and other to join a new worker node.

```
You can now join any number of control-plane nodes by copying certificate authorities
and service account keys on each node and then running the following as root:

  kubeadm join LB_IP:6443 --token znnlha.6Gfn1vlkunwpz36b \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:dc8834a2a5b4ada38a1ab9831e4cae67e9d64cb585458a194018f3ba5a82ac4U \
    --control-plane 

Then you can join any number of worker nodes by running the following on each as root:

kubeadm join LB_IP:6443 --token znnlha.6sfn1vlkunwpz36A \
    --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:dc8834a2a5b4ada38a1ab9831e4cae68e9d64cb585458a194018f3ba5a82ac4e
```

I am not using `--upload-certs` for transfering the certificates from one control plane to another. I am doing it manually.

But when I run the above `kubeadm join` command to add a new control plane, on the one of my other master nodes,say `master2`, I am getting an error like following :

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap: failed to get config map: Get "https://LB_IP:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config?timeout=10s": dial tcp LB_IP:6443: connect: connection refused
```

Comment: @PjoterS can u plese help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just came across the same issue - in my case the problem was that when hitting GCP's loadbalancer from an instance which is also a target of this loadbalancer, the request will always land on the same instance from where you sent the request.

Based on this:

- you run `kubeadm init` on `Node A` using `LB_IP`. `LB_IP` gets resolved to `Node A`. Everything works as expected, as you are creating a new cluster.
- you run `kubeadm join` on Node B using `LB_IP`. `LB_IP` gets resolved to `Node B`, while the master you just initialized is on `Node A`. `Node B` doesn't have anything running on port 6443, thus you get connection refused error.

A simple solution is to remove the instance you are running `kubeadm join` on from the loadbalancer targets. You can re-add it right after successful join.

Comment: So you are suggesting to run kubeadm join in Node B and then add the ip of Node B in load balancer, right?? So once we add two ips in load balancer, once my NodeA Master 1 is down, control plane will automatically shift to NodeB Master2, right??

Comment: Exactly, it's only important that Node B is not a target of load balancer at the moment you actually run `kubeadm join`. You can add it as a target as soon as join is complete.